# ActionMap / KeyBindings - <identifier> expected error

Tags: java

I'm attempting to get an ImageIcon PNG image to move on my GUI, in Java. But I get this error:

```
MainClass.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
                                x = x--;
                                 ^
1 error
```

This is my code:

```
public class MainClass extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JLabel label;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Character Face Left - Bronze.png");

        int x = 300;
        int y = 300;

        label = new JLabel(image);
        label.setLayout(null);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rover: Bound to Earth");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), LEFT);
        actionMap.put(LEFT, new AbstractAction() {
            x--;
        } );

        label.setLocation(x,y);
    }
}
```

What I want to have happen is, when the "A" key is pressed, the ImageIcon moves to the left. I've attempted to set the location of the ImageIcon with x and y, and have the x-- happen when the "A" key is pressed, but again, I'm getting the error.

Comment: `x` is a local variable of the `main` method, and as such i will be destroyed as the `main` method finishes...

Comment: You set the layout to `null`, but no for the frame, that would lay out its children, but for the label itself...

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're telling me to do, how do I get it to not be a local variable of the main method? Putting it before the method starts didn't help. And what do you mean by "but no for the frame"?

Comment: After setting up the listeners for the key event, (which BTW does not works,) the main method will end, and the variable `x` will be destroyed...

Comment: Why is that it will be destroyed? And, why does the Key Event not work - I thought I followed the tutorials correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code a bit:

```
// originally this extended JPanel, but was never used...
public class MainClass extends AbstractAction
{
    // he label to be moved
    JLabel label;
    // the co-ordinates   
    int x = 300;
    int y = 300;
    // constructor... moved your code from main() to here...
    public MainClass()
    {
        // instantiating panel and label
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon( "Character Face Left - Bronze.png" );
        // but as i do no have your image, i added some text...
        label = new JLabel( "IMG", image, JLabel.CENTER );
        // and specified he size of the label
        label.setSize( 100, 50 );
        // initial positioning
        label.setLocation( x, y );
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Rover: Bound to Earth" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        // the frame is the one hat lays out its child components
        // so it is the one to set he layout to null, not the label...
        frame.setLayout( null );
        frame.add( label );
        frame.setSize( 500, 500 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
        // setting up he key event, however his still not working
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap( JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW );
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
        // your LEFT identifier should be an object, that is unique,
        // i just used the string "LEFT"....
        inputMap.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_A, 0 ), "LEFT" );
        actionMap.put( "LEFT", this );
    }
    // the action's listener
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        // decrement x, and also move the label
        x -= 10;
        label.setLocation( x, y );
    }
    // a new main()
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // AWT uses a special thread to queue, dispatch and execute events
        // the SWING GUI must run on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () ->
        {
            new MainClass();
        } );
    }
}
```

This code will run, but still not working, as the `Key Press->Acion` transition is broken somewhere. I do not know much about `Action`s to be real help here on.
Try asking about it in a new question...

Comment: The `T` key on my keyboard is not working sometimes, so if you found somehing is no making sense, try to add a `t` in the word....